# How can i read older versions of Microsoft Office Add-Ins documentation?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, documentation, outlook-addin

My boss wanted an vsto outlook add in and I'm very close to finishing it. I need to write
the manifest and release it (and hope everything works).

So long story short, is there a way to read the old documentation?

When I look up the documentation, it changed, and I can't find the things I'm looking for. I find a lot
of the new stuff for the new Outlook (preview) but not for the old one. Stuff like the "old one is no more supported. That's how you can import your code",
"the new one is in javascript" - i wrote the code in C# with VS2022.
Like everything changed in few weeks.

I want to look up the old VSTO documentation about the manifest and how to integrate it, deploy it and maybe other stuff if some bugs appear.
(also strange: the docs say a vs solution creates 2 projects (app + manifest), but my solution has by default only 1 project, the app/add-in I assume).

Comment: Hi, asking for tutorials etc. is considered off-topic on SO. Also, being more detailed when asking questions, helps getting an answer. E.g. what is "the old one"? Any hint, like a version number, would be helpful. Please read the [how to ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi, well, it's a little hard to give exact information, because I work only 1 day of the week and the project is a few months old now. so for example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/one-outlook this page was updated yesterday, and it says "VSTO and COM add-ins are still supported in classic Outlook on Windows." But I can't the docs for them.

Comment: Why do you need to deploy the manifest file? That is not a web add-in where you could deploy just a manifest and get you web application working in Office applications. Instead, you need to create an installer for your add-in where you could include dependencies and other actions if required. See my post for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can start from the [Walkthrough: Create your first VSTO Add-in for Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-outlook?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp) page. There you can find all the required information like [Outlook object model overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/outlook-object-model-overview?view=vs-2022) and [Outlook solutions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/outlook-solutions?view=vs-2022).

There is no need to deal with VSTO manifests. What you really need is to create an installer for your add-in, there are two main ways for deploying VSTO add-ins:

- [Deploy an Office solution by using ClickOnce](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-an-office-solution-by-using-clickonce?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp)
- [Deploying a VSTO Solution Using Windows Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-a-vsto-solution-by-using-windows-installer?view=vs-2022)

Answer (score 0):

i created an installer and it was installed successfully, but the add-in didn't show up, and we had difficulties due to some security issues. So maybe i was wrong in thinking it could be a "missing manifest".
Thx for the answers and the information.